# How to format if statements to print in simple table format

Tags: python, if-statement

We have to calculate grades for a co-convened class and the results need to look like this:
[desired results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDEnK.png)

this is what I have so far which works fine but is not formatted properly, I am loss on how to format it because of the if statements

```
n,s,p = input("Input your Name, section, and points separated by a comma").split(",")
st= float(s)
po= float(p)
if st == 435:
grade = (po/600)*100
if grade < 60:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "F")
elif grade >= 60:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "D")
elif grade >= 70:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "C")
elif grade >= 80:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "B")
elif grade >= 90:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "A")
elif st == 535:
grade = (po/700)*100
if grade < 60:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "F")
elif grade >= 60:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "D")
elif grade >= 70:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "C")
elif grade >= 80:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "B")
elif grade >= 90:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print("GSP", s, "A")
```

Update this is what I have now, my only issue is getting the output to leave enough room for people with longer names without pushing the grade value too far to the right.

```
n,s,p = input("Input your ame, section, and points separated by a comma").split(",")

st= float(s)
po= float(p)
if st == 435:
grade = (po/600)*100
if grade < 60:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+s,n, "F"))
elif 60 <= grade < 70:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+s,n, "D"))
elif 70 <= grade < 80:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+s,n, "C"))
elif 80 <= grade < 90:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+s,n, "B"))
elif 90 <= grade < 100:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+s,n, "A"))

elif st == 535:
grade = (po/700) * 100
if grade < 60:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+ s, n, "F"))
elif 60 <= grade < 70:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+ s, n, "D"))
elif 70 <= grade < 80:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+ s, n, "C"))
elif 80 <= grade < 90:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+ s, n, "B"))
elif 90 <= grade < 100:
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format("GSP "+ s, n, "A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For one, every block starts with:

```
print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
```

So, you could just print that first and then check the conditions:

```
n, s, p = input("Input your Name, section, and points separated by a comma").split(",")
st = float(s)
po = float(p)
if st == 435:
    grade = (po / 600) * 100
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    if grade < 60:
        print("GSP", s, "F")
    elif grade >= 60:
        print("GSP", s, "D")
    elif grade >= 70:
        print("GSP", s, "C")
    elif grade >= 80:
        print("GSP", s, "B")
    elif grade >= 90:
        print("GSP", s, "A")
elif st == 535:
    grade = (po / 700) * 100
    print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
    if grade < 60:
        print("GSP", s, "F")
    elif grade >= 60:
        print("GSP", s, "D")
    elif grade >= 70:
        print("GSP", s, "C")
    elif grade >= 80:
        print("GSP", s, "B")
    elif grade >= 90:
        print("GSP", s, "A")
```

However, the only thing that differs here is the letter grade, based on the number grade - the print statements are the same otherwise.

And the only thing different between the section in the outer `if` is the way `grade` is computed, based on `st` (section).

So, how about:

```
# get the input and convert to numbers
n, s, p = input("Input your Name, section, and points separated by a comma: ").split(",")
st = float(s)
po = float(p)

# check section and compute grade
if st == 435:
    grade = (po / 600) * 100
elif st == 535:
    grade = (po / 700) * 100
else:
    grade = 0
    print('unknown section!')
    exit()

# look up letter grade for grade
grades = [(90, 'A'), (80, 'B'), (70, 'C'), (60, 'D'), (0, 'F')]
letter_grade = 'unknown'
for g, letter in grades:
    if grade > g:
        letter_grade = letter
        break

# print result
print("SECTION", "STUDENT", "GRADE")
print("GSP", s, letter_grade)
```

If you had more sections, you could perform a similar kind of logic for computing the grade as is being used for looking up the letter. The key idea is to DRY (don't repeat yourself). It's generally a good idea, because repeating code creates a situation where you might change one part, but forget to update another. And the way the solution is now written, all the actual data sits in one place, which makes it easier to maintain.

To format the text to line up nicely, replace the last line with:

```
print('{:7s} {:7s} {:5s}'.format('GSP', s, letter_grade))
```

Or, similarly:

```
print(f'{"GSP":7s} {s:7s} {letter_grade:5s}')
```

Comment: this was my professors response to my asking how to format, "In fact, the format() method is much easier and convenient since you do not need to install any additional modules.

A string is an object in Python. The string object has a format() method that allows you to feed values into replacement fields. " -- So I am assuming it needs a format and replacement field I am just confused on how to do that with if statements, I am new to this and the replacements we have done have been pretty simple.

Comment: I added a line about formatting - the same reasoning applies though, note how I just had to update a single line to change formatting, where you would have to update all the lines in the code you had.

Comment: Thank you so much, we aren't quite to that simplified way of getting these results, but this will be helpful in the future, and the formatting helped a lot! Very much appreciated, it was so much simpler than my professors explanation which was multiple paragraphs.

Comment: Hopefully my last question here but if the last name is too long it pushes the grade value far away from the grade column any way to fix?